# Unexpected result when using the hex encoding on Buffer object

Tags: node.js, buffer, web3js

All private keys listed have been changed and they are addresses on a test network anyway so don't get any ideas!

**The issue:**
I'm attempting to use the Hex encoding of a Buffer object, however, when I try and use the Buffer.from(key, 'hex') function, I get an empty Buffer object back. Anytime I omit the Hex encoding, the Buffer object acts normally.

Any ideas as to what the root of the issue is?

```
 const privateKey1 = Buffer.from('0x6ee345295b6b2a6df6e06ba3bb5f09a301acf5b1af3c23452025373e15fdb230', 'hex')

 console.log(privateKey1)
```

The above console.log returns `<Buffer >`

```
const privateKey2 = Buffer.from('0x6ee88295b6b2a6df6e06ea3ab5f09a401acf5b1af3c75672025373e15edb230')
    
console.log(privateKey2)
```

The above console.log returns `<Buffer 30 78 36 65 65 38 37 32 32 39 35 62 36 62 32 61 36 64 66 36 65 30 36 63 61 33 61 62 35 66 30 39 61 34 30 31 61 63 66 35 62 31 61 66 33 63 37 38 33 30 ... 16 more bytes>`

Answer (score 1):

I also run into the same problem
The way I resolved it was to use a substring to get rid of the 0x value that is at the beginning of the private key

```
let private_key = '0x6ee88295b6b2a6df6e06ea3ab5f09a401acf5b1af3c75672025373e15edb230';

const privateKey2 = Buffer.from(private_key.substring(2) , 'hex')
```